# Optimizing Django queryset related comparisons

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a Django app where users upload photos, and leave comments under them. The data models to reflect these objects are `Photo` and `PhotoComment` respectively.

There's a third data model called `PhotoThreadSubscription`. Whenever a user comments under a photo, the user is subscribed to that particular thread via creating an object in `PhotoThreadSubscription`. This way, he/she can be apprised of comments left in the same thread by other users subsequently.

```
class PhotoThreadSubscription(models.Model):
    viewer = models.ForeignKey(User)
    viewed_at = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)
    which_photo = models.ForeignKey(Photo)
```

Every time a user comments under a photo, I update the `viewed_at` attribute of the user's `PhotoThreadSubscription` object for that particular photo. Any comments by *other users* that have a submission time of greater than `viewed_at` for that particular thread are therefore **new**.

Suppose I have a queryset of comments, all belonging to unique photos that never repeat. I want to traverse through this queryset and find **the latest unseen comment**.

Currently, I'm trying this in a very DB heavy way:

```
latest_unseen_comment = PhotoComment(id=1) #i.e. a very old comment
for comment in comments:
    if comment.submitted_on > PhotoThreadSubscription.objects.get(viewer=user, which_photo_id=comment.which_photo_id).viewed_at and comment.submitted_on > latest_unseen_comment.submitted_on:
        latest_unseen_comment = comment
```

This is obviously not a good way to do it. For one, I don't want to do DB calls in a for loop. How do I manage the above in one call? Specifically, how do I get the relevant `PhotoThreadSubscription` queryset in one call, and next, how do I use that to calculate the **max_unseen_comment**? I'm highly confused right now.

---

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    image_file = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_photo_to_location, storage=OverwriteStorage())
    upload_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)
    latest_comment = models.ForeignKey(blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class PhotoComment(models.Model):
    which_photo = models.ForeignKey(Photo)
    text = models.TextField(validators=[MaxLengthValidator(250)])
    submitted_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
    submitted_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

---

Please ask for clarification if the question seemed hazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will do it in a single query:

```
latest_unseen_comment = (
    comments.filter(which_photo__photothreadsubscription__viewer=user,
                    which_photo__photothreadsubscription__viewed_at__lt=F("submitted_on"))
            .order_by("-submitted_on")
            .first()
)
```

The key here is using [`F expressions`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.F) so that the comparison can be done with each comment's individual date, rather than using a single date hardcoded in the query. After filtering the queryset to only include the comments that are unseen, we then `order_by` the date of the comment and take the first one.